Can I populate fields in a list using a for loop?
I am new to C# so pardon me if I stumble over concepts or syntax.
I have a trading program where I use lists to store potential trades and data related to the quality of the trade.  On of the lists contains fields that store incremental information from the chart.  An example of how I do that is below.  Each subsequent field is populated the same way but with a different threshold based on the boundaries.  The boundary matches the field name. For example, the .SHL20 field hold a value related to objects on a chart that are between 0 and 20 ticks from the potential trade.  .SHL30 is up to 30 ticks away, etc.
There are 2 things I want to do.  First is to populate the fields.  Then I would like to be able to choose which field I want to use as a trade filter.
I can populate the fields as I did below, but that is a lot of code to do the same thing.
I can also set up a case statement that chooses from among the different fields based on which threshold I want to use.  But again, that is a lot of code since If my threshold is 40, I know I want the data in the .SHL40 field
But if it were possible to do something like name the fields based on a loop, and query on a loop I could do something like this
(My list name in the example below is IFVGopen)
for(x = 10 ; x < 100 ; index = x + 10)
{
IFVGopen[index].x = SwingHLopen.Count(p =>  p.type == -type && p.eqhlCount < 2 && (tradeSide - p.price) * type - index >= 0     && (p.price - tradeSide) * type + index + 10 > 0)
}

then I'd like to extract the filter value by being able to get a variable, say 40, and find the value for IFVG[index].40
Is somethin like this possible?
I'm currently populating the fields manually like below.
IFVGopen[index].SHL20    = SwingHLopen.Count(p =>   p.type == -type && p.eqhlCount < 2 && (tradeSide - p.price) * type - 10 >= 0 && (p.price - tradeSide) * type + 20 > 0);

IFVGopen[index].SHL30    = SwingHLopen.Count(p =>   p.type == -type && p.eqhlCount < 2 && (tradeSide - p.price) * type - 10 >= 0 && (p.price - tradeSide) * type + 30 > 0);

IFVGopen[index].SHL40    = SwingHLopen.Count(p =>   p.type == -type && p.eqhlCount < 2 && (tradeSide - p.price) * type - 10 >= 0 && (p.price - tradeSide) * type + 40 > 0);

IFVGopen[index].SHL50    = SwingHLopen.Count(p =>   p.type == -type && p.eqhlCount < 2 && (tradeSide - p.price) * type - 10 >= 0 && (p.price - tradeSide) * type + 50 > 0);

IFVGopen[index].SHL60    = SwingHLopen.Count(p =>   p.type == -type && p.eqhlCount < 2 && (tradeSide - p.price) * type - 10 >= 0 && (p.price - tradeSide) * type + 60 > 0);

I can do it all manually as I described above, but it sems like there should be a more elegant way to accomplish the same thing

The art of coding is to write the code as much as readable as you can. The for-loop code is very hard to read, which makes it tough to see what you're doing there. Try to move that code into a function, This way it doesn't have to be a single statement, but multi lined. Add some comment what it is doing. (for example why are you using -type with the minus infront? Every operation has a meaning.

thanks Jeroen.  I will clean it up so that it makes more sense to some that isn't me.  I've also learned that when I don't do a good job of explaining myself in the code, I forget why I was doing stuff
